# How to use *args instead of explicit function signature in a numba overload

Tags: python, numba

I have many (~169) functions (with ~45 unique signatures) that I am overloading with numba. I would like to add some additional logic that is the same to all the functions so I was trying to use a decorator but it seems that the 'inner' function in the decorator has to have the same signature as the function it is decorating.

This is a working example for one specific signature:

```py
from numba import njit, extending, objmode
import warnings

def func(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

def warn(func):
    def inner(a, b, c):
        result = func(a, b, c)
        if not result:
            with objmode:
                warnings.warn("Result is zero")
        return result
    return inner

@extending.overload(func)
def func_overload(a, b, c):
    @warn
    @extending.register_jitable
    def impl(a, b, c):
        return a + b - c
    return impl

@njit
def func_nb(a, b, c):
    return func(a, b, c)


args = 1, 2, 3
print(func_nb(*args), func(*args))
```

Output:

```
0 6
/var/folders/v7/vq2l7f812yd450mn3wwmrhtc0000gn/T/ipykernel_15095/773019809.py:36: UserWarning: Result is zero
  print(func_nb(*args), func(*args))
```

but I would like a single decorator to work for all of my signatures. I've tried using `*args`:

```
def warn(func):
    def inner(*args):
        result = func(*args)
        if not result:
            with objmode:
                warnings.warn("Result is zero")
        return result
    return inner
```

but I get the following error:

```
/var/folders/v7/vq2l7f812yd450mn3wwmrhtc0000gn/T/ipykernel_15488/784317548.py:38: NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning: Code using Numba extension API maybe depending on 'old_style' error-capturing, which is deprecated and will be replaced by 'new_style' in a future release. See details at https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-old-style-numba-captured-errors
Exception origin:
  File "/Users/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/typing/templates.py", line 577, in _validate_sigs
    a = ty_args[:ty_args.index(b[-1]) + 1]
                               ~^^^^

  return func(a, b, c)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-2.ipynb Cell 5 line 4
     44 args = 1, 2, 3
     45 args2 = *args, 4
---> 46 print(func_nb(*args), func(*args))

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "
    465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
    466         e.patch_message(msg)
--> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
    471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args.<locals>.error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407     raise e
    408 else:
--> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function func at 0x104455e40>) found for signature:
 
 >>> func(int64, int64, int64)
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload in function 'func_overload': File: ../../../../../../var/folders/v7/vq2l7f812yd450mn3wwmrhtc0000gn/T/ipykernel_15488/784317548.py: Line 20.
    With argument(s): '(int64, int64, int64)':
   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
     IndexError: list index out of range
  raised from /Users/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/typing/templates.py:577

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function func at 0x104455e40>)
During: typing of call at /var/folders/v7/vq2l7f812yd450mn3wwmrhtc0000gn/T/ipykernel_15488/784317548.py (38)


File "../../../../../../var/folders/v7/vq2l7f812yd450mn3wwmrhtc0000gn/T/ipykernel_15488/784317548.py", line 38:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

and with [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```
_tmpl = """
def inner({0}):
    result = func({0})
    if not result:
        with objmode:
            warnings.warn("Result is zero")
    return result
"""

def warn(args):
    def warn_args(func):
        exec(_tmpl.format(args))
        return locals()["inner"]
    return warn_args
```

and then changing the call on line 18 from `@warn` to `@warn("a, b, c")`
but it gets stuck in a recursive loop.
So is there any way to do this without having to add this logic to the functions individually or to make decorators for all the signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `@warn` decorator to the `impl` function replaces the `impl` function with the `inner` function.
That is, the `func_overload` function actually returns the `inner` function.

```py
@extending.overload(func)
def func_overload(a, b, c):
    @warn
    @extending.register_jitable
    def impl(a, b, c):
        return a + b - c
    
    print(impl)  # <function warn.<locals>.inner>
    return impl
```

However, the `func_overload` function must return a function with the same signature as itself.
This is the cause of the error.

The simplest workaround would be to disable strict checking of the overload.

```py
@extending.overload(func, strict=False)  # Just added strict=False.
def func_overload(a, b, c):
    @warn
    @extending.register_jitable
    def impl(a, b, c):
        return a + b - c

    return impl
```